# jQuery slim-scroll not scrolling to the browser search item

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slimscroll

I am using jQuery [slim-scroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll). If I search for an item using browser search (ctrl + f), then the document is not scrolling to the search result item. Is there a way to solve this? If so, help me solve this.

Thank you..

Comment: it is an inbuilt feature of browser itseld and it is not possible in your case because the text after div is hidden accoring to the css overflow hidden and the browser cant access the text and it will not sow or go to that text.

Comment: `slim-scroll` uses JavaScript to scroll the browser window to a certain location on the page. When you search using the browser itself, this is separate to your webpage JavaScript and won't behave in the same way as `slim-scroll`

Comment: @Abhinav is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @timothyclifford can't we do this using this slim-scroll?

Comment: Intercepting browser behaviour is not something you should try and do. First of all it's a hack and rarely works as expected. Secondly you are modifying behaviour users expect and they will not normally appreciate this being modified.

Comment: when i am looking in slim-scroll it is working perfect